# Allowing Java's ScriptEngineManager to access certain Java Methods

Tags: java

Is it possible to access Java methods from inside ScriptEngineManager.

I found out how to use the Invocable invoke function method, but now I need the opposite to happen.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = "var results = system.foo('example');            \n" +
                    "                                                \n" +
                    "if(results == \"hello\") {                      \n" +
                    "  print(\"ding dong.\");                        \n" +
                    "}                                               \n";
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.eval(source);
  }
}

public class System {
  public static String foo (String x) throws Exception {
    // do something with x
    return("hello");
  }
}
```

So when I run system.foo it should run the method in System.foo.

Comment: If you are looking for a JavaScript engine I would use the latest version of Rhino. The version that is packaged with the JRE is old.

Comment: I need to be able to specify what classes they can access.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this using [Mozilla Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) is much easier. Say your wanted to expose `System.out` to your scripts:

```
Context cx = Context.enter();
Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();
Object wrappedOut = Context.javaToJS(System.out, scope);
ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "out", wrappedOut);
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
var hello = "Hello World";
out.println(hello);
```

You can also expose individual Java methods by extending the Function class in the Rhino library and they exposing it to your scripts in a similar fashion.

Comment: So does this mean the not all methods will be exposed?

Comment: You can expose an object or you can wrap a method by implementing the Function object in the Rhino library.